# PostgreSQL: match a group of keywords (any) with multilanguage text

Tags: postgresql, text, matching

In Postgre 12.0 I need to check whether certain column containing text (which can be in multiple languages, with no reliable indication of what language the text is actually in) contains any of a group of keywords.
Keyword can be a single word or a specific phrase. (case matching, however, is undesirable)

If there is a match, I would like to return the respective row.

I have a table that has a numeric identifier of a document (id1), numeric identifier of a section of a document (id2) and a varchar column containing text in HTML (contents)

Keywords are stored in a separate table keywords, simply as id and varchar (containg the keyword/"search term")

I suppose I should be using a query containing to_tsvector()

```
SELECT 
mt.*
FROM 
mytable mt
WHERE 
to_tsvector('simple', mt.contents) @@
to_tsquery('simple', kw.keyword);
```

As you can see, this won't run, as I need to get a list of keyword for that match.

The only idea I had was to first construct a string for matching by concatenating all keywords from keyword table
and then using that, as in

```
SELECT 
mt.*
FROM 
mytable mt
WHERE 
to_tsvector('simple', mt.contents) @@
to_tsquery('simple', 'kw1 | kw2 | kw3 ... | kwN');
```

But for that I am still struggling with how to parse that, the only thing I came up with is something like this:

```
SELECT 
mt.*
FROM 
mytable mt
WHERE 
to_tsvector('simple', mt.contents) @@
to_tsquery('simple', (SELECT 
string_agg(keyword, ' | ') AS keyword
FROM keywords) );
```

Can you help?

Comment: Your last example works.  So what are you asking?

Comment: It does not really work, because I have keywords/patterns to match that can be comprised of multiple words. So this: `SELECT 
to_tsvector('simple', 'This is a test sentence where I would like to match the following specific words') @@ to_tsquery('simple',  'kw1 | words'); `  works, but this does not: `SELECT 
to_tsvector('simple', 'This is a test sentence where I would like to match the following specific words') @@ to_tsquery('simple',  'kw1 | specific words');`   (so that I would get a match ONLY if  "specific words" was found in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the phrase search feature.  So for the example in your comment  you would want to use the tsquery `kw1 | specific <-> words`.  You could store the multi-word phrases in your table with the `<->` already there, or maybe use regexp_replace to turn the spaces into `<->`

```
SELECT 
mt.*
FROM 
mytable mt
WHERE 
to_tsvector('simple', mt.contents) @@
to_tsquery('simple', (SELECT 
string_agg(regexp_replace(keyword,' ',' <-> ','g'), ' | ') AS keyword
FROM keywords) );
```

If you have hyphenated words or phrases, that mess this up.